# Write line to file with new text?

Tags: php, file

I am trying to update part of a company address in all html files within a directory.  I got stuck trying to figure out the best way to insert the new line back into the file.  Below is what I got thus far.

```
<?php
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo){
    foreach(glob($fileinfo.'/*.*') as $file) {
        if(is_writable($file)){
            $file_parts = pathinfo($file);

        switch($file_parts['extension'])
        {
            case "html":
                $lines = file($file);
                foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
                    $newline = str_replace("Suite 425", "Suite 800", $line);
                    echo $newline;
                }
            break;
         }
       }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: why do you need to do this you can simply use a database for it

Comment: I would honestly just use `sed` for something like this. It is a linux command line 'streaming editor' that will replace text based on regular expression.

Comment: I'd suggest using command-line tools like "find" and "sed" instead of PHP, if You are on a Unix-like shell.

Comment: I am not in a Unix-like shell.  The requirement is to do it in php.  I'm not changing the file names, I'm changing particular content within the file.

Comment: Then You may do it like this: 1. Load the whole file into a string. 2. Replace the things You need to replace in that string. 3. If the string changed, save it over the old file. Be sure to make backup before You start experimenting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this, but it is not tested, test before you try on all the files, or keep a safe backup :)

```
<?php
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo){
    foreach(glob($fileinfo.'/*.*') as $file) {
        if(is_writable($file)){
            $file_parts = pathinfo($file);

        switch($file_parts['extension'])
        {
            case "html":
                $lines = file($file);
                $to_write='';
                $file_modified=false;
                foreach ($lines as $line_num => $line) {
                    $newline = str_replace("Suite 425", "Suite 800", $line);
                    $to_write.=$newline;
                    if($newline!=$line){
                       $file_modified=true;
                    }
                }
                if($file_modified){
                   $file_handle=fopen($file, 'w');
                   fwrite($file_handle, $to_write);
                   fclose($file_handle);
                }
            break;
         }
       }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: thank you for the direction that you applied.  I'm new to reading and writing from files.  This not only worked perfectly, but gave excellent perspective.